# ./hidapi/hidapi/hidapi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, abi, ubuntu, build-from-source

I cloned go-ethereum, and used `go mod vender`.
When make, it's failed! and the error info is:

```
# github.com/karalabe/usb
vendor/github.com/karalabe/usb/hid_enabled.go:22:10: fatal error: ./hidapi/hidapi/hidapi.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include "./hidapi/hidapi/hidapi.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: You will need to install `libhidapi` for your system.

Comment: Thanks! But if  I compile without "go mod vender", it's ok...   Is there any way to disable the usb wallet?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: no. So i compile without  "go mod vendor"

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue when deploying to Google App Engine the other day.

A workaround is to

```
$ go mod vendor
$ cd vendor/github.com/karalabe
$ rm -rf usb
$ git clone https://github.com/karalabe/usb
```

This solves the problem of missing files *I have no idea though if there are other unwanted side effects*!
So use with caution.

Comment: Thanks, it's work!    the 2nd step is :   cd vendor/github.com/karalabe